# Pipe request to S3 in Node

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3

so I have an app which lets you upload a file over an api, the file is the request and currently I am piping to a writeStream to write to the file system.

What I'd like to do is pipe directly to S3 instead of the filesystem.

My code for streaming to the file system is:

```
var valid_ext = ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg'],
    max_size = 2*1024*1024,
    name = req.headers['x-file-name'],
    api = req.headers['x-api-key'],
    size = parseInt(req.headers['content-length'], 10),
    ext = path.extname(name).toLowerCase(),
    filename = safeFilename(path.basename(name, ext)+ext),
    timestamp = new Date().getTime(),
    filepath = 'public/files/' + timestamp + '_' + filename,
    imagePath = '/files/' + timestamp + '_' + filename,
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

  if(valid_ext.indexOf(ext.substr(1)) === -1) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "File does not match an accepted filetype."}));
    return;
  }

  if(filename === ext) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "Invalid file name."}));
    return;
  }

  if(size > max_size) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "File size exceeds the maximum limit."}));
    return;
  }

  req.pipe(writeStream);
  req.on('end', function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('There was an error writing the file: ' + err);
      res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "There was an error uploading the file."}));
    } else {
      res.send(imagePath);
    }
  });
```

Which works just fine, however I can't find anything anywhere about modifying this to just pipe to S3 instead, so here is what I came up with:

```
var body = fs.createReadStream();
    req.pipe(body);
    req.on('end', function() {
      s3.upload({
        Bucket: 'rawnet-flytrap',
        Key: project.pivotal_id + '/' + timestamp + '_' + filename, // I assume this will create a folder for me but I'm not sure :/
        Body: body
      }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
      }).send(function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
      });
    });
```

But this isn't working, can anyone show me what to do? Like I said I can;t find anything online about it that makes any sense.

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked this : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

Comment: I've seen that but it doesn't do what I want, my 'client side' is a plugin that will be on lots of different sites, it sends data to my back end via an api, I need my backend to handle the the file transfer to S3

Comment: I managed it using s3-streaming-upload in the end.